# .NET Core get array in array from config.json

Tags: .net-core, app-config

I have an issue where an array object in my config.json is coming back as empty.  In the following code, gridFields will come back as empty.

```
{"grids": [{
  "name": "Grid1"
  "gridFields": [
    {
      "Name": "Something",
      "Label": "Something"
    },
    {
      "Name": "SomethingElse",
      "Label": "SomethingElse"
    }]
  },
  {"name": "Grid2"
   "gridFields": [
    {
      "Name": "Something",
      "Label": "Something"
    }]
  }]
}
```

I have matching POCOs and made sure the names match up as follows.

```
public class Grid
{
  public string name { get; set; }
  public gridFields gridFields {get; set;}
}
public class gridFields
{
    public List<gridField> GridFields { get; set; } = new List<gridField>();
    public int Count => GridFields.Count();
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GridFields.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
public class gridField
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

In my startup I have the following

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        var config = new List<Grid>();
        Configuration.Bind("grids", config);
        services.AddSingleton(config);
    }
```

The config.gridFields ends up holding no values. I have values for name, but not gridFields.  Even if I make gridFields List  it comes back null.

My question is if there is someway following this current code that I can get the data out of this array in array, or do I need to do something completely different.  Why isn't .net core able to bind every object it comes across underneath the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example json misses a `,` after the name of each grid.

```
{
  "name": "Grid2",
  "gridFields":
  [{
    "Name": "Something",
    "Label": "Something"
  }]
}
```

You have a list of `gridField` directly under the Grid in the Json.
In the Code however you use another object, `GridFields`.
You should remove the gridfiels class and use a list of gridField in the Grid class:

```cs
public class Grid
{
  public string name { get; set; }
  public List<gridField> gridFields {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I was shortening down the json.  It was correct in my code.  Making the code change suggested worked.  It's kind of a shame that it can't figure out what the base type is on it's own.